# How can I fetch data from machine learning model deployed on heroku?

Tags: vue.js, heroku

I have machine learing model deployed on Heroku. Now I want to fetch the model's predictions from the Vue.js app. Can I do it running the app locally or do I have to deploy the app on Heroku as well?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an API layer to do show. Please provide detail of how you deployed the modal ? did you use pickle or something else. In any case you can fatch from local vue js app as well no need to deploy it on heroku.